# Java program to find a whether a number is divisible by 11 using an array with specific instructions

Tags: java, arrays, math

Well, it has to be determined by adding the digits at odd and even positions and if they're equal, then it's divisible by 11. This has to be done using an array. I wrote the whole code but it's not working. Can anyone point out my mistakes?

The corrected program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class divby11
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); //Initilize Scanner method       
        System.out.println("Enter the number:"); //Ask user for input
        int n=scan.nextInt(); //User input
        int copy=n; //Copy variable to prevent n's value being erased
        int c=0; //Count of digits
        int dig; //The digit (i.e. the last digit of n) extracted
        while(copy!=0) //Runs till the value gets 0
        {
            copy/=10; //Getting to the next number 
            c++; //Count post-fixed by 1
        }
        copy=n;
        int arr[]=new int[c]; //Fix length of array
        int i=0; //Set the increment counter; starts at 0
        while(copy!=0) //Digit extraction
        {          
            dig=copy%10; //The digit extracted
            copy/=10; //Integer division by 10 to go to next digit
            arr[i]=dig; //Set the digit to the array index
            i++; //Post-fix the increment counter
        }        
        int odd=0; //Set value
        int even=0; //Set value
        for(int j=1;j<c;j+=2) //For-loop for adding the value of the odd index nos. of the arr[] 
        { 
            odd+=arr[j]; //The sum of the series
        }           
        for(int k=0;k<c;k+=2) //For-loop for adding the values of the even index nos. of the arr[] 
        {
            even+=arr[k]; //The sum of the series
        }
        if(odd==even) //Divisible by 11
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is divisible by 11.");
        else if(odd!=even) //Indivisible by 11
            System.out.println("The number " + n + " is not divisible by 11.");
    }  
}
```

And this already has downvotes. :'(

Comment: `for(int j=1;j<=c/2;j+=2)` - it looks like you're only iterating over the  _first half_ of the array (as opposed to half the total elements).  Besides not using `%` (which gives you the remainder, if any, from division), you don't need an array to do this either...  I'm assuming this is a homework assignment?  Oh, in the future, "It doesn't work" isn't sufficient information for us - please list what's going wrong, in as much detail as possible.  After you get your issue worked out, ask for advise on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your two other major problems are in the loop starting with `while(n!=0) //Digit extraction` (and the fact that you have a subloop).  If you start breaking up your method into smaller ones (ie, write something that just gets an array of the first `n` digits of a number `k`, where both of those are parameters to the method), things will become a little easier for you.  Writing shorter methods generally decreases problems you will face.  You should be able to do everything with static methods, no need to instantiate a runner object.

Comment: I did what you asked me to but I got a`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at divby11.main(divby11.java:30)` error. And this isn't technically homework just some enthusiast's timepass given by the teacher.

Comment: Think about your ending conditions for your final two loops, and why the general recommendation is to use `<` only.  Did the teacher ask you to use arrays specifically, or just to do this by adding/subtracting digits?

Comment: I just realized that I set `c` to zero and then in the `//Digit extraction` subloop I set the limit to `c-1`.

Comment: My idea didn't work. It's the same error but on line 24. Secondly, I did it without arrays already, but the challenge she gave was to do it with arrays.

Comment: Like I said, try writing a method that extracts the "first" (from 0) `n` digits of a number `k`, where you supply both `n` and `k`.  The return type should be a basic `int[]`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with homework, you know. But when you bring homework (even an optional exercise) here, there are [certain guidelines you are supposed to follow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812).

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I did make an attempt at solving it and I also posted the error that was being displayed, I didn't use a homework tag and I certainly used code I understood. And I also admitted that "this isn't technically homework just some enthusiast's timepass given by the teacher."

Comment: There are several small errors in your code which I'm sure you can find and correct by using `println` to see the values of your variables at various points. The main problem is that the algorithm doesn't work. 209 is divisible by 11 but the even and odd sums are different. If you want to make this work you would have to make it a recursive method where you compute `odd` and `even`. If they are equal the number is divisible by 11. If they are not equal you need to recursively call the method on the integer `Math.abs(even - odd)`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, could you explain. I can certainly extract the first `n` digits but how do I save them to the array index?

Comment: That came out wrong.  Your current loop is actually coping each digit to every index in the array.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, that's fixed. And now, I get a new result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i=0;
while(n!=0) //Digit extraction
    {          
           dig=n%10;
           n/=10;
           arr[i] = dig;
           i++;
    }
n=copy;
```

nested loop is not needed

also n value is changed,you need to keep it for last print

```
int odd=0;
int even=0;
for(int j=1;j<c;j+=2) //Adding odd digits
{ 
    odd+=arr[j];
}
//if(c%2==1)
//c++;
for(int k=0;k<c;k+=2) //Adding even digits
{
    even+=arr[k];
}
```

your loops where going till half of the array and

```
for(int k=0;k<=c;c+=2)//you incremented c instead of k
```

Comment: Tried, I get `The number 0 is divisible by 11.` as the result.

Comment: You are changing both n and copy value in your code.So when you print n,value is zero.

Comment: I saw that and fixed it. Similar result.

Comment: You have 2 while loops one with copy.Did you use copy=n; after it?The n value is set to 0 somewhere in your code

Comment: No, exactly. :) That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop conditions here `for(int j=1;j<=c;j+=2)` and here `for(int k=0;k<=c;c+=2)` from `<=` to `<`, and remove this `if(c%2==1) c++;`

Comment: Tried. Doesn't fix it.

Comment: Nah. Try again. There may be other problems as well, but then you have yo be more specific about what you mean by "it". Or, just get a debugger.

Comment: The errors were elsewhere. I didn't reset copy and the while loop's for subloop was a failure. Anyway, thanks for helping. :)